# Why don't I use viewModelScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{ } with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is Ok, so I think Code B is Ok too, but in fact Code C can be compiled, why ?

What's wrong with Code B ?

**Code  A**

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
          
}
```

**Code B**

```
viewModelScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{

}
```

**Code C**

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){

}
```

Comment: `viewModelScope` is a val. It's not a function such as `CoroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext)` or `CoroutineScope.launch(...)`, so your `Code B` cannot be compiled because of a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code A** ✅

**Code B** ❌

**Code C** ✅

### Explanation

**Code A**

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
          
}
```

It works because it creates a new `CoroutineScope` with the `Dispatchers.IO` and launches a coroutine in that scope using the `launch` function.

*Source code*
[image]

**Code B**

```
viewModelScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{

}
```

It does not work because `viewModelScope` is a property that returns a `CoroutineScope` tied to the lifecycle of the `ViewModel`. However the `launch` function is not a member of the `CoroutineScope` class, so it can not be called from `viewModelScope` directly.

*Source code*

[image]

**Code C**

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){

}
```

It does work because `viewModelScope` is a property that returns a `CoroutineScope` tied to the lifecycle of the `ViewModel`. In this code, the launch function is called on the `viewModelScope` object returned by the property, and the `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher is passed as a parameter to the `launch` function.

*Source code*

[image]

Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

It’s as simple as `CoroutineScope` and `launch` are functions, and `viewModelScope` is a property.

- `CoroutineScope()` is a function that takes a CoroutineContext parameter that it will use for jobs that it launches.
- `launch` is a function that takes an optional CoroutineContext parameter that it will merge with its scope’s context to use in its own coroutine.
- `viewModelScope` is an instance of a CoroutineScope. It is not an invokeable function.

Answer (score 1):

In Code A , You are creating you own coroutine using `CoroutineScope` Builder by giving `Dispatcher` so that's fine as it allows you to create it your own

In Code B , you are using viewModelScope which is extension property not (not accepting any arguments) coroutine builder like `CoroutineScope` or `GlobalScope` as you can see it's source code as mentioned below

```
public val ViewModel.viewModelScope: CoroutineScope
    get() {
        val scope: CoroutineScope? = this.getTag(JOB_KEY)
        if (scope != null) {
            return scope
        }
        return setTagIfAbsent(
            JOB_KEY,
            CloseableCoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)
        )
    }
```

In Code C , you are using `launch` which is extension function of `CoroutineScope` and accepting arguments as mentioned in source code

```
public fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job {
    val newContext = newCoroutineContext(context)
    val coroutine = if (start.isLazy)
        LazyStandaloneCoroutine(newContext, block) else
        StandaloneCoroutine(newContext, active = true)
    coroutine.start(start, coroutine, block)
    return coroutine
}
```